# Query returning records with duplicate data because of the wrong data in one of the columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates, street-address

I have a record of an employee but my query is returning 2 records of this employee because the address column is different between the 2. How can solve this problem? Is it something that can be done? EMP_ID, CUS_LAST_NAME, CUS_FIRST_NAME, and GUARDIAN_ADDRESS are from 3 separate tables.

Example:

```
ID          EMP_ID      CUS_LAST_NAME   CUS_FIRST_NAME  GUARDIAN_ADDRESS
00000000    11111111    Jackson         Michael         1111 Street Apt 1

ID          EMP_ID      CUS_LAST_NAME   CUS_FIRST_NAME  GUARDIAN_ADDRESS
00000000    11111111    Jackson         Michael         1111 Street
```

Comment: Which of the addresses do you want to see? First? Most recent? Current?

Comment: How you expect solve this problem?  Show us db schema, sample data and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: How do you have different employee records with the same EMP_ID?  Is Address stored separately from Employee?

Comment: @MarkoJuvančič - both records were created and updated at the same time.

Comment: @Jerrad - yes, address is from another table.

Comment: You need to at least show your actual query.

Comment: You have been shown by 4 different people how to solve this. Those people each wrote a different solution that should work based on the vague explanation of the problem. It is time for you to put in some effort on this. Show us the table structures, some sample data and what you expect for output.

Answer (score 0):

The quick and dirty way with `max()`:

```
select id, emp_id, emp_last_name, emp_first_name, max(address) as address
from employees
group by id, emp_id, emp_last_name, emp_first_name
```

Alternative using: [**`top with ties`**](http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/use-top-filter-with-ties-option)

```
select top 1 with ties
    id, emp_id, emp_last_name, emp_first_name, address
from employees
order by row_number() over (partition by emp_id order by address desc)
```

rextester demo for both: http://rextester.com/EGGA75008

Comment: still showing duplicates. both addresses showed up.

Answer (score 0):

if you can't the delete  one of the two 
if you don't matter which address  the select return  you can  use an aggregation function for get one row only

```
select ID , EMP_ID , EMP_LAST_NAME,   EMP_FIRST_NAME,  min(ADDRESS)
from my_table 
group by ID , EMP_ID , EMP_LAST_NAME,   EMP_FIRST_NAME
```

Comment: Still showing duplicates. both addresses showed up.

Comment: impossible  ... check for you query or you data .. show the exact query you are using and a proper data sample ..

Comment: if the values are form 3 tables  update you question and add  a (minimal) data sample based on the 3 tables

Answer (score 0):

If you want detect what employee have duplicates entries.

```
SELECT *
FROM employees
WHERE EMP_ID IN (
     SELECT EMP_ID
     FROM employees
     GROUP BY EMP_ID
     HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
   )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
--start with unique list of clients
    SELECT DISTINCT a.ID, a.EMP_ID, e.EMP_LAST_NAME, e.EMP_FIRST_NAME,     e.ADDRESS
FROM TABLE1 a
--attach on employee data on id
    OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 b.EMP_LAST_NAME, b.EMP_FIRST_NAME, b.ADDRESS
    FROM TABLE2 b
    WHERE a.id = b.id 
--use order by clause to change order and choose what top employee record u     want to choose
    ORDER BY b.address 
    ) e
```